# Variable acumula datos en un foreach - PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un `foreach` que recorre unos array para mostrarme unos link de las imagenes. Cuando creo mas de un block se muestran en el 2do las imagenes de éste y las de el primer block.

```
if ( isset( $block['images'] ) ){

  foreach(array_column($block['images'], 'image') as $idImagen) {
    $url[] = brc_make_link_relative_if_local( wp_get_attachment_url( $idImagen ) );
  }

  $data_array[$section_key][$section_data_key][$block_key]['images'] = $url;
}
```

Y como se puede apreciar se repiten los enlaces. Supongo que no debe ser algo dificil, sino mas bien algun metodo de limpiar la variable que estoy returnando o algo asi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver en images del segundo block se estan repitiendo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que `$url` está almacenando todos los elementos que se procesan en el `foreach`... sin embargo una vez has volcado los elementos no reseteas el array, por lo que en sucesivas pasadas irá teniendo cada vez más elementos.

Deberías reiniciar la variable antes de cada `foreach`:

```
if ( isset( $block['images'] ) ){

  unset($url);
  $url= array();

  foreach(array_column($block['images'], 'image') as $idImagen) {
    $url[] = brc_make_link_relative_if_local( wp_get_attachment_url( $idImagen ) );
  }

  $data_array[$section_key][$section_data_key][$block_key]['images'] = $url;
}
```

Comment: Perfecto tal cual, esa era la solucion. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: @SantiagoD'Antuoni, debería marcar la respuesta como la solución a la pregunta formulada ;)